# What does "@" mean in a C/C++'s macro?

Tags: c, macros, cross-compiling, openwrt

I cross-compiled a firmware with [openwrt](http://www.openwrt.org), and a file is strange named `libbfd.h` and I compiling failed, I have ever seen it. In `libbfd.h` line 83:

```
79 #define BFD_HOST_64BIT_LONG @BFD_HOST_64BIT_LONG@
80 #define BFD_HOST_64BIT_LONG_LONG @BFD_HOST_64BIT_LONG_LONG@
81 #if @BFD_HOST_64_BIT_DEFINED@
82 #define BFD_HOST_64_BIT @BFD_HOST_64_BIT@
83 #define BFD_HOST_U_64_BIT @BFD_HOST_U_64_BIT@
84 typedef BFD_HOST_64_BIT bfd_int64_t;
85 typedef BFD_HOST_U_64_BIT bfd_uint64_t;
86 #endif
```

here `BFD_HOST_U_64_BIT` is defined as `@BFD_HOST_64_BIT@`, what's mean with "@", I tested in a test file, can't compiling. Could anybody help me? Thx!

Comment: my guess it, it's a variable that is going to be replaced by a build script?

Comment: Were I to hazard a guess, this is a `config` substitution file that is populated with *real* values during the configuration+build of the OpenWRT toolkit for your platform. It is likely not meant to ever ben included directly, but rather used to generate a version that you *do* use (or at least OpenWRT uses).

Comment: @sehe Yes, there maybe a script, but I couldn't find it now, because I compile it automatization. I just `make menuconfig` and after config it type `make`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@VARIABLES@` are replaced with values during configuration on the target system.

See [this page of the autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html).

Did you do the typical:

```
./configure
make
```

To build it?  Those should have constant values.

Comment: No, I was built it automatization. I just typed `make menuconfig` and after cofig it I type `make`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but you'll need to figure out how to run the pre-processing step in the build.  This is probably just the first of many errors you'll encounter without doing that.

Comment: I use OpenWrt's autobuild system, follow the step here http://kamikaze.openwrt.org/docs/openwrt.html#x1-410002.1.1, the complete commands are `./script/feeds update -a` `./script/feeds install -a` `make menuconfig` `make`

Answer (score 0):

The `@` character is not part of the C Standard execution character set, primarily because it was not part of the original ASCII standard.

Unless it's part of an implementation's extension to C, the `@`s will need to be removed before the C compiler sees them.